# How can I write blackboard bold Latin capital letters in Plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, blackboard

In LaTeX, you can use commands like `\mathbb{C}` (in `amsfonts`) or `\mathds{C}` (in `mathds`) to get blackboard bold letters. But how would I get them in plain TeX? I tried `{\ds C}` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Just standard setup; the fonts are `msbm10` and related ones.

```
\font\tenamsb=msbm10 \font\sevenamsb=msbm7 \font\fiveamsb=msbm5
\newfam\bbfam
\textfont\bbfam=\tenamsb
\scriptfont\bbfam=\sevenamsb
\scriptscriptfont\bbfam=\fiveamsb

\def\bbb{\fam\bbfam}

${\bbb N}$ is the set of natural numbers.

\bye
```

[image]

Of course, for serious math typesetting you should use AMS-TeX

```
\input amstex
\loadmsbm

$\Bbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers.

\bye
```

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\font\mbb=msbm10 
\newfam\bbb
\textfont\bbb=\mbb

$ x \in {\fam\bbb Z} $

\bye
```