# Loading amsfonts package in plain TeX

Tags: pdftex, amsfonts

Sorry for the zero-intelligence question, but how do I load a package in a Plain TeX document? (No LaTeX please.) Specifically, I'd like to load the amsfonts package such as to have access to the \mathbb fonts. I'm using pdftex from the command line, on a mac.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301848/15925 help?

Comment: I think "Plain TeX" would be more idiomatic than "pure TeX"...

Comment: Hi, thanks. Concerning the referred page, the command "\input amstex" (in first solution) returns a file not found complaint, though I see that I have amstex.sty at /opt/local/share/texmf-live/tex/latex/amsmath on my computer. How do I point pdftex to look there? (I'm assuming that specifying the full path is not the correct solution.)

Comment: You need to install the package which provides `amstex.tex` in order to input it. You can't load LaTeX packages in plain TeX.